# How to check a variable on Cisco ASA and then remove it

Tags: python, ansible

I have several hundred ASA devices with running captures but the devices and captures all have different names.  Therefore I am trying to use Ansible to log into each device and run the show capture command and then pass the variable name of the capture to Ansible and then return the input string :
'no capture '
I can run the Ansible script to run 'show capture' on each device but am not sure how to have Ansible take the unique variable from each device and then in turn run the no capture command.
Do I need to use Python in collaboration with Ansible here ?
Any pointers as to how I could do this would be gratefully apprecriated.

I have already run an Ansible script to login to each device and obtain the capture command but unable to identify how to change that string into a variable

Comment: I don't understand your question; can you show the commands you would run from ios? It sounds like you just want to use `set_fact:` to grab the capture variable, then feed that back into a templated `ios_command:`

Comment: I can't read the formatting in a comment, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53916228/edit) to make it legible

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, please find a more legible output below of an example show command, so I would like to change each of the 3 capture lines below to be  : 'no capture <capname e.g. MYCAP1>'                       - MY_ASA# sh cap | i capture  capture MYCAP1 type raw-data interface wan      - I have tested the regex replace and only seem to get 'no capture' returned

Comment: That's an odd thing to put into a comment, given how I **explicitly** said "edit your question" and "comment formatting isn't designed for what you're doing". But fine, I hope you are able to get someone else to help you

Answer (score 0):

*I'm preemptively putting an answer here based on what I am _guessing_ the format is of the response, because I think the skeleton of it is right, it just might need tweaking after seeing the real output*

```
- ios_command:
    commands:
    - sh capture
  register: the_caps
- ios_command:
    commands: '{{ no_cap_commands }}'
  vars:
    no_cap_commands: >-
      {{ the_caps.stdout | 
         select('match', '^capture ') | 
         map('regex_replace', '^capture ([^ ]+) .*', 'no capture \1') |
         list }}
```

Obviously if you want to only switch off some of the captures, you'll have to adjust that `select` to narrow them down, or otherwise reduce the list that arrives at that `regex_replace` filter.